# How to read Json Object?

Tags: json

My remote server returns the Json data in the following format.

Json data:

```
{
"some_id-1":{"dueDate":"22","desc":"22"},
"some_id-2":{"dueDate":"aa","desc":"aa"},
"some_id-3":{"dueDate":"22","desc":"22"}
}
```

"some_id-x" is unique id generated at server. Now if I understood the structure of JSON correctly, the way above object read is like this: 
"Json Object contains three members with three different objects" - Is it right understanding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's correct, your JSON object contains 3 elements where each one is an object.
Have a look at the json page to clarify the concepts. [json.org](http://json.org/)

if you want to loop all your elements try doing something like that, i've tested it in my firefox and it works , all desc elements are printed:

```
<html>
<script>
yourjsonvar = {
"some_id-1":{"dueDate":"22","desc":"22"},
"some_id-2":{"dueDate":"aa","desc":"aa"},
"some_id-3":{"dueDate":"22","desc":"22"}
} 
for (var key in yourjsonvar) {
  if (yourjsonvar.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    alert((yourjsonvar[key])['desc']);
  }
}
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Now considering "some_id-x" is unique id returned for each object by server. How to use it in my client program. I want to loop through each and show it to user for further modification to "desc" property of a particular object. I tried to do that but failed.

Comment: hi i've modified my answer try it.

Comment: The above piece of javascript code returns more than 3 keys. i.e. $promise, $get etc